# What's wrong with this For loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I can't get this program to count the spaces, I have a feeling there is a logic error in the loop, but I am too inexperienced to figure it out myself. Any tips?

```
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
String myString = keyboard.next();
int numBlanks = 0;

//find string length
int length = myString.length() - 1;
System.out.println("length " + length);

for(int sequence = 0; sequence >= length; ++sequence);
{

    if(myString.charAt(length)==' ')
    {
        numBlanks += 1;
        length -= length;
    }
    else 
        length -= length;

}
```

Comment: ( With standard coding conventions, you wouldn't get the problem of the spurious semicolon on the `for` loop. )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few bugs I can see:

**Semicolon at the end of for loop**. Remove it.

Next

```
sequence >= length
```

should be

```
sequence <= length
```

and

```
if(myString.charAt(length)==' ')
```

should be

```
if(myString.charAt(sequence)==' ')
```

and you need to change `length` at all as you are already changing `sequence`.

So we get:

```
for(int sequence = 0; sequence <= length; ++sequence) {

    if(myString.charAt(sequence)==' ') {
        numBlanks += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but think there should be a "don't" in: and you need to change length at all

Answer (score 3):

`sequence >= length` is spoken aloud as "`sequence` is greater than or equal to `length`." It is initialized to zero. When will it be greater than or equal to `length`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the errors others have pointed out, there are violations of convention here; you're calculating the length as n - 1, and then comparing <= (well, >=, but should be <=).  Typically, unless there is very good reason, our for loops look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

In your case, this would be expressed as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

It is also conventional to stick with "i" as the loop variable, unless there's good reason to use another; in your case, "sequence" is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**First issue:**

change

```
for(int sequence = 0; sequence >= length; ++sequence);
```

to

```
for(int sequence = 0; sequence <= length; ++sequence);  //flipped >= to <=
```

**Second issue:**

change

```
I am too inexperienced to figure it out myself.
```

to

```
This will be some good practice for debugging.  //int confidence should never be negative
```

:D

Comment: While you're fixing the 'first issue', remember to also remove the extra semicolon at the end of the for sentence :-)